# Moment.js doesn't support Microsoft/ISO format?

Tags: momentjs, iso

I'm working on a project where I'm given the Microsoft date/time format, which seems to be exactly like a standard [ISO formatting](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003169814.htm).

When I try to format a date with Moment.js, it doesn't come out right. For example, the format I'm provided with has 'yy' for the 2-digit year and 'd' for a 1-digit day-of-month.

When I look at the [Moment.js format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) documentation I realize the it doesn't even support it? That's a bit odd? Why would it not support a standard?

Or am I doing something wrong? Am I missing something?

I'd really hate to try to write an ISO to Moment.js format converter.

Has anyone had the same problems? If so, how have you resolved this?

---

**Update 2017.10.16 17:32:**

After getting a good question from Matt Johnson down in the comment, I read my post again and realized I've been working for so long in this "embedded" web project that I probably wasn't quite clear as to what is meant by "windows giving me a date format". So I wrote the following in response to his question:

@MattJohnson, what I mean is that the web project I'm working on for a client is an IE embedded (OLE) inside a Windows application (compiled binary, not web). The JavaScript portion of the web application "talks" to the desktop application in order to receive/send data. One of the data I receive is a "dateFormat" and "timeFormat" property. The values I receive, I'm told come directly from the Windows machine (based on user configuration of that OS). It happens that years/days are all lowercase, causing Moment.js to not being able to format dates properly. Thus the conversion I now have.

---

Examples:

Calling

> moment().format();

Will produce

> "2017-10-13T13:24:47-04:00"

Now, if I want to format it according to the Moment.js documentation, I'd do this:

> moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY');

To get this:

> "10/13/2017"

The problem is that Windows passes along this format:

> "dd/MM/yyyy"

So when I call Moment with it, like:

> moment().format('dd/MM/yyyy');

Giving me this:

> "Ve/30/yyyy"

While I was expecting this:

> 13/10/2017

When I look at many other date formatting libraries, I see that they all support the 'yyyy', 'dd' and 'MM' structure. But not Moment.js.

---

**Update 2017.10.13 16:41:**

I did a comparison of Microsoft's date/time format to that of Moment.js and saw the differences.

```
* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Unit            Microsoft           Examples                Moment.js           Differnces?
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  day             d, dd               1, 01                   D, DD               Yes, case
 *  day of week     ddd, dddd           Fri, Friday             ddd, dddd           None
 *  month           M, MM, MMM, MMMM    8, 08, Oct., October    M, MM, MMM, MMMM    None
 *  year            yy, yyyy            17, 2017                YY, YYYY            Yes, case
 *  
 *  hour            h, hh, H, HH        3, 03, 15, 15           h, hh, H, HH        None
 *  minutes         m, mm               9, 09                   m, mm               None
 *  seconds         s, ss               5, 05                   s, ss               None
 */
```

Using that information, I quickly wrote a format conversion function:

```
function windowsFormatToMomentJSFormat(windowsFormat) {
  var format = windowsFormat;

  console.log("Converting date format...");

  if (!windowsFormat) return format;

  console.log(" > From    : '" + windowsFormat + "'");

  format = format.replace(/y/g, 'Y');       // Fix case for years
  format = format.replace(/d{4}/g, '#');    // Protect 4-digit DOW sequence
  format = format.replace(/d{3}/g, '&');    // Protect 3-digit DOW sequence
  format = format.replace(/d/g, 'D');       // Fix case for days
  format = format.replace(/#/g, 'dddd');    // Restore our sequence
  format = format.replace(/&/g, 'ddd');     // Restore our sequence

  console.log(" > To      : '" + format + "'");
  console.log(" > Applied : '" + moment().format(format) + "'");

  return format;
}
```

It seems to work well, although I wish I was much better at advanced REGEX in order optimize the function and remove the protect/restore code.

So now, my Windows format strings seems to be processed correctly by Moment.js' format() function.

Comment: I don't understand what are you to do. Are you passing a date to moment.js from ASP.NET?

Comment: @Dmitry I updated my questions with some examples. Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that ISO8601 does not define what legends to use inside 
date parsers and formatters. Those are library/PL specific. ISO8601 specifies the date format itself. `moment().format();` produces a date-time in that ISO format. And it seems that `moment` uses legends from https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime. Python for example uses completely different legend format https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior. And by the way your `dd/mm/yyyy` completely contradicts ISO.

Comment: When you say: `"The problem is that Windows passes along this format"` what *specifically* do you mean?  Also you show `dd/mm/yyyy`, but I'm guessing you probably meant `dd/MM/yyyy`?  Additionally, Dmitry is correct - ISO8601 does not deal with these type of formatting tokens at all.  The only standard that does is called LDML, which is part of the Unicode CLDR project.  Neither Moment or Windows or .NET are fully LDML compliant in this regard, and neither are most other languages.  Everyone's formatting tokens are different.  So - what is your basis that they should be the same somehow?

Comment: @MattJohnson, what I mean is that the web project I'm working on for a client is an IE embedded (OLE) inside a Windows application (compiled binary, not web). The JavaScript portion of the web application "talks" to the desktop application in order to receive/send data. One of the data I receive is a "dateFormat" and "timeFormat" property. The values I receive, I'm told come directly from the Windows machine (based on use configuration of that OS). It happens that years/days are all lowercase, causing Moment.js to not being able to render dates properly. Thus the conversion I now have.

Comment: @MattJohnson, I've tried to do a search for LDML but I didn't find anything pertaining to date/time formatting. Would there be a link you could provide? Thank you, I appreciate it.

Comment: @MattJohnson, "I'm guessing you probably meant dd/MM/yyyy" ... yes that is correct. I've made the changes in my question.

Comment: The relevant part of LDML is [here](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table), but that's not going to help for the situation you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need a conversion function, because date/time formatting tokens are different across various libraries and platforms.  There isn't one already developed, that I am aware of.

- [This is the list of formatting tokens supported in Moment](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)
- [This is the list of formatting tokens supported in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings), which is roughly the same as the ones used in the Windows date/time region settings.
- [Here is a moment plugin that does almost what you want](https://github.com/MadMG/moment-jdateformatparser), but it uses Java's token set, not Windows.  You could base your implementation on that.

Note that your current function is missing several tokens.  In particular the am/pm separator needs translation, and you should think about literals and escape sequences as well.

Comment: Thank you Matt for your post along with its links and all. As for my function, yes I realize it is missing conversions as you pointed out. I just need the strict minimum at this time to move forward. I'll try and contact the Moment.js guys to see if they have any plans in adding support for various formatters. I'll accept your answer as most helpful (along with your comments). Thanks!